# Why is boundingRectWithSize wrong when using UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle?

Tags: ios8, nsstring, uilabel, uifont

I have found that a call to `boundingRectWithSize` is extremely incorrect, missing an entire additional line, when called with `NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]`. However, using the font `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17.f]`, it is just fine.

Here is test code showing the bug:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *measureText = @"I'm the king of Portmanteaus ... My students slow clap";

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(226.f, CGFLOAT_MAX);

    UIFont *targetFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];

    CGRect stringRect = [measureText boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                                         options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                      attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : targetFont }
                                                         context:nil];        

    UILabel *drawLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:stringRect];
    drawLabel.font = targetFont;
    [self.view addSubview:drawLabel];
    drawLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    drawLabel.text = measureText;
    drawLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
}
```

And the output:

[image]

However, if I make `targetFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17.f];`

It renders properly:

[image]

In the first case, the size is {226.20200000000008, 42.281000000000006}, but in the correct second case the size is {228.64999999999998, 60.366999999999997}. Therefore, this is not a rounding issue; this is missing an entire new line.

Is it wrong to pass `[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]` as an argument into `boundingRectWithSize`?

---

**Edit**

Per the comments in the answer below, I believe there is a bug with how iOS treats three periods in connection with the proceeding word. I have added this code:

```
measureText = [measureText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" ..." withString:@"…"];
```

and it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A label adds a little margin round the outside of the text, and you have not allowed for that.

If, instead, you use a custom UIView exactly the size of the string rect, you will see that the text fits perfectly:

[image]

Here's the code I used. In the view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *measureText = @"I'm the king of Portmanteaus ... My students slow clap";
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(226.f, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    UIFont *targetFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    CGRect stringRect = [measureText boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                                  options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                               attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : targetFont }
                                                  context:nil];
    stringRect.origin = CGPointMake(100,100);
    StringDrawer* sd = [[StringDrawer alloc] initWithFrame:stringRect];
    [self.view addSubview:sd];
    [sd draw:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:measureText attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : targetFont }]];
}
```

And here is String Drawer (a UIView subclass):

```
@interface StringDrawer()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSAttributedString* text;
@end

@implementation StringDrawer

- (instancetype) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    return self;
}

- (void) draw: (NSAttributedString*) text {
    self.text = text;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.text drawInRect:rect];
}

@end
```

Also, if your purpose is to make a label that contains the text by sizing its height, why not let Auto Layout do its thing? This next screen shot is a UILabel, with a width constraint 226, and no height constraint. I've assigned it your font and your text, in code. As you can see, it has sized itself to accommodate all the text:

[image]

That was achieved by this code, and no more was needed:

```
NSString *measureText = @"I'm the king of Portmanteaus ... My students slow clap";    
UIFont *targetFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
self.lab.font = targetFont;
self.lab.text = measureText;
```

Comment: Also I think the `"..."` is causing trouble, in some way I cannot quite put my finger on. If you change it to an ellipsis character, or "xxx", you get the expected results.

Comment: Also you are not allowing for the fact that a UILabel should not have a non-integral size. We should be integerizing the rect...

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me - there is not a published margin on UILabel as far as I know, and I should not have to abandon my use of UILabel for a UIView + drawInRect if I need to be able to size it properly. Isn't the use of boundingRectWithSize + UILabel a very common design pattern on iOS? Also - the issue is that it's not giving me a third line for my text, so even rounding up wouldn't make a difference. IDK why your example is able to fit on a mere 2 lines....

Comment: I'm not totally happy with my answer either. I've proved _something_, though: I've proved that the given text does fit into the rectangle size that it says it fits into.

Comment: But I still think what you're doing is very odd. We have auto layout, so why not use it and let the label set its own height, as it wants to do? I've added that to my answer; as you can see, it works perfectly - we get a label of the given width that automatically exactly accommodates the text.

Comment: Another weird thing I notice is that text fits into a view of size (226,43), but if you make it _wider_, (227,43), it no longer fits! This is because it wraps "portmanteau" too soon. It is as if it tries to keep it with the "..."

Comment: Also, your code works if you add `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`. So it looks like it is treating the "..." as part of the preceding word if it can. I think that's the real heart of the matter.

Comment: I think you might be right about the "..." being mis-treated here...I will add code to auto-sub "..." with an ellipses char, and file a bug with Apple. Thanks matt !